# How to check the height of the div to rearrange div blocks

Tags: jquery, facebook-iframe, autoresize, facebook-comments, jquery-masonry

I'm using jQuery Masonry in my site to display blog posts. And each post block has Facebook Comments Box added in it. When there's a new comment, the container div expands and unfortunately overlaps with the one beneath. In this case I need to re run the Masonry script to reload the blocks.
[image: Screenshot]

So I'm using [Ben Alman's Jquery Resize Event Plugin](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-resize/examples/resize/) to check the change in the height of the div so that the Masonry script repositions the block according to their new size and avoids overlaps.

Although it's not working and there seems to be no errors when I check it with firebug. I'm a total newbie on Jquery and I'm hoping I'm just making a simple mistake here.

If you want to have a look at it please check bjk-tribun.com
You'll see the overlapping when you enter some comments in the comments box.

```
$(function(){
  // Bind the resize event. When any test element's size changes, update its
  // corresponding info div.
  var iframe = $(".fb_iframe_widget");

  // Called once the Iframe's content is loaded.
  iframe.load(function(){
    // The Iframe's child page BODY element.
    var iframe_content = iframe.contents().find('body');

    // Bind the resize event. When the iframe's size changes, update its height as
    // well as the corresponding info div.
    iframe_content.resize(function(){
      var elem = $(this);

      // Resize the IFrame.
      iframe.css({ height: elem.outerHeight( true ) });

      $('#sort').masonry(reloadItems);

    // Resize the Iframe and update the info div immediately.
    iframe_content.resize();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of jQuery you use, you might need to add the px unit in your css property:

```
iframe.css({ height: elem.outerHeight( true ) + "px" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I don't know why but once I turned of colorbox.js which was a lightbox plugin the Jquery Masonry plugin began reacting to div resize. So if anybody runs into the same problem they should first try to disable other jquery plugins to not to spend their whole week on this matter.

I also disabled Ben Alman's plugin that I inserted above. Masonry is enough to handle the resize event.